# Can't start EC2 instance in VPC via lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I have followed the [following tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/) to start/stop instances by ID.

I didn't supply the VPC information for either `stopEC2Instances` or `startEC2Instance` functions.

**Problem**: While it works fine when stopping the instances, the `startEC2Instances` function doesn't do its job.

I'm wondering if `boto3` has changed in someway since the tutorial was written? I checked out the `boto3` API to make sure, but `start_instances` is still the same function.

I haven't changed any code than what's on the linked article above.

**UPDATE**:

CloudWatch Logs for the latest successful run of the `startEC2Instances` function (it didn't work as expected and still didn't start the instances)

```
START RequestId: 663ce39a-8534-11e8-9928-2b8c600ed800 Version: $LATEST
started your instances: REDACTED
END RequestId: 663ce39a-8534-11e8-9928-2b8c600ed800
REPORT RequestId: 663ce39a-8534-11e8-9928-2b8c600ed800  Duration: 1055.49 ms    Billed Duration: 1100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB    Max Memory Used: 56 MB  
START RequestId: 7f7e57ac-8534-11e8-9c44-41bb6e4a0724 Version: $LATEST
started your instances: REDACTED
END RequestId: 7f7e57ac-8534-11e8-9c44-41bb6e4a0724
REPORT RequestId: 7f7e57ac-8534-11e8-9c44-41bb6e4a0724  Duration: 420.79 ms Billed Duration: 500 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB
```

**UPDATE 2**
I'm copying the policy document and the code from the document above, I have made no changes whatsoever.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `startEC2Instance` code:

```
import boto3
# Enter the region your instances are in. Include only the region without specifying Availability Zone; e.g.; 'us-east-1'
region = 'us-east-1'
# Enter your instances here: ex. ['X-XXXXXXXX', 'X-XXXXXXXX']
instances = ['REDACTED']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about the actual issue you are encountering other than "doesn't do its job". Please edit your question to include the actual error message you receive.

Comment: @MarkB there is no error. When I test the function it says it is successful. But the EC2 instances I want to start, have not started. I always try to start the instances after a minute or two after they have been stopped.

Comment: Check the Lambda function's logs in CloudWatch logs for any errors. Add a try/catch to your code to make sure you are catching (and logging) any exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: @MarkB please check update

Comment: Maybe you should show your code. There is nothing to go on here.

Comment: The code is in the tutorial link I posted up there. There was nothing that changed, so I didn't post it here for sake of brevity

Comment: You should probably modify the code to show the output of `ec2.start_instances()` — it provides the InstanceId of any instances launched (just put it in a `print()` statement). Also, make sure you are looking in the correct region to see whether they launched.

Comment: Show us the code, just mask out the instance id.  It is wild guessing without the code.

Comment: @mootmoot please have a look at the update

Comment: Please try the policy and roles as shown here : 
https://blog.goodmirek.com/periodically-start-and-stop-ec2-instance-bf25c01e68f1

Comment: @mootmoot even this approach does not work, but it worked if I manually detached my secondary EBS volume. However, I had to attach it manually once the server started

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to have been the encrypted volume attached to my instance. This volume was set to boot on startup, and was thus causing problems. I tried using different IAM EBS actions including `AttachVolume`, `DetachVolume`, `DescribeVolumes`, etc.

But the action that finally worked was a KMS action `CreateGrant` with the resource set to the `key ID` of the key that encrypted the volume.

Comment: There is always small piece of missing info that the documentation did not cover ;-)

Answer (score -1):

For me, I have added the Role which is attached to the Lambda function, in a KMS Key policy as a Key Administrator and Key User.